# Haskell: writing a Boolean function that gives if an element is in a list

Tags: haskell, hugs

I'm completely new to Haskell and I'm trying to write a function that if given a list of integers and another integer n will returns a Boolean whether the integer is in the list or not.

So I wrote:

```
l=[n..m]
occurs :: Int -> [Int] ->Bool
occurs x l
  | x `elem` l = True
  | otherwise  = False
```

But I get the syntax error of 'unexpected =' or whatever.

[image: screenshot of error message]

Comment: Your function compiles. Can you please include the full error message?

Comment: Which means `occurs = elem` right? So you didn't really do anything.

Comment: "But I get the syntax error of 'unexpected =` or whatever".  Please don't post descriptions of your problems like this, instead take the time to type out a detailed description of your problem, along with the full text of the error message.

Comment: Have you checked that your whitespace is consistent? Make sure you aren't using any tabs in your code, since that can make things appear correct in your editor, but not to GHC.

Comment: http://oi61.tinypic.com/2rrw8at.jpg

That's a snapshot of the error I get. I've actually used tabs in my code, since I could not figure out how to 'jump lines' so to speak, without executing the code. And lastly, I'm using 'WinHugs'. Apologies for not including this information earlier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't do anything on Haskell due to syntax errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787186/i-cant-do-anything-on-haskell-due-to-syntax-errors). Please edit future questions instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 6):

The function `occurs` compiles fine. However, the expression `l = [n..m]` is nonsense, unless suitable definitions for `n` and `m` already exist.

There is a larger issue with your code. Note that `elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool` which is **very** similar to the type of `occurs`, especially considering `Int` is an instance of `Eq`.

Also, the `l` in your definition of `occurs` is not the same than the `l = [m..n]` on the line above. The `l` in `occurs` is a *free variable* which is bound to some value when `occurs` is called.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question, the desirable function is by essence `elem`

```
foo :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
foo x l = x `elem` l
```

foo will return either true or false.

Comment: You could also just write `foo = elem`

Comment: Absolutely that's why I was saying "by essence is elem", the answer provided is just to show the mecanism of elem.