# I can't do anything on Haskell due to syntax errors

Tags: haskell, syntax, hugs

I can execute simply operations, like

```
Hugs> 2+2
```

for instance. Or any operation, for that matter.

But when it comes to actually trying to define a function, e.g:

```
occurs :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool 
occurs x l = x `elem` l
```

Then I get the message:

```
ERROR - Syntax error in input (unexpected `=')
```

I also get `` unexpected `::' `` in other cases. I'm using WinHugs.

Answer (score 6):

When typing in a function in interactive mode, you need to use `let`, and you also have to separate lines with a semicolon:

```
let occurs :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool; occurs x l = x `elem` l
```

Comment: I copied what you wrote and got:

>ERROR - Syntax error in expression (unexpected end of input)

Comment: @user3482534 It works fine for me, but I'm using GHCi instead of Hugs.  I would honestly recommend switching to GHC (and the [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/)) over Hugs, it has much better support for some of the more modern features, especially considering the last build of Hugs was around 2006.  But that is a side note to your problem.  Can you try it with curly braces around the definition, like `let { occurs :: ... ; occurs x l = ... }`?

Comment: @bheklilr is correct. Install Haskell Platform and run with GHCi or .hs files. Hugs is likely to be more of an impedance than a help in learning Haskell.

Answer (score 6):

You need to save the function in a file (*.hs) and load it via `:load <filename>`, since the prompt accepts only expressions.

> [8.5. How do I enter function definitions?](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/users_guide/faq.html#AEN1890)
>
> The Hugs prompt only accepts expressions for evaluation. You can create a file containing a Haskell module, and load that (see [Section 2.2](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/users_guide/module-commands.html) for details).

If you want to experiment with function definitions in a REPL environment, I recommend you to use GHCi instead.